# Javascript DOM not returning any value

Tags: javascript, dom

I attempted to run through DOM validator, but it has not helped. I think there is a simple logic error but I can't find it. Is it in the lack of `return()` statement? I am new to DOM, it's my first attempt. I thought the `getByElementId` was the return?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Check Pay</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function whichType(radiobutton)
  {
    buttoncollection = document.getElementsByName("radiobutton");
    if (buttoncollection[0].checked == true) 
    {
  document.getElementById().value = "Salaried Employee";
    }
    if (buttoncollection[1].checked == true) 
    {
     document.getElementById().value = "Full Time Hourly Employee";
    }
    if (buttoncollection[2].checked == true) 
    {
    document.getElementById().value = "Part Time Hourly Employee";
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Type of employee:</h1>
<p>Check the type of employee:</p>
<form name = "payInfo">
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="fullsal"> Full      time-salaried</><br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="fullhr"> Full time-hourly</> <br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="parttime"> Part-time</><br>
<input type="button" name="toClick" value="Select type"  onClick="whichType()"/>
<input type="text" id="theType" name="theType" size="30"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forget the argument to `getElementById` function, you probably want: `document.getElementById('theType')`

Comment: What is `</>`? it's invalid tag.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```js
function whichType(radiobutton){
    var buttoncollection = document.getElementsByName('radiobutton'),
                  output = document.getElementById('theType'); 
    if(buttoncollection[0].checked) output.value = 'Salaried Employee';
    if(buttoncollection[1].checked) output.value = 'Full Time Hourly Employee';
    if(buttoncollection[2].checked) output.value = 'Part Time Hourly Employee';
}
```

```html
<h1>Type of employee:</h1>
<p>Check the type of employee:</p>
<form name = "payInfo">
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="fullsal"> Full time-salaried<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="fullhr"> Full time-hourly <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="parttime"> Part-time<br>
    <input type="button" name="toClick" value="Select type"  onClick="whichType()"/>
    <input type="text" id="theType" name="theType" size="30"/>
</form>
```

If yes, then the problem was (as already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002384/javascript-dom-not-returning-any-value/30002645#comment48123357_30002384) by jcubic) that you forgot to specify *which* element: `document.getElementById().value`

Also note that `radio_element.checked` returns a `true`/`false` value, so no need for `buttoncollection[0].checked === true` (that's just wastefull for the environment and your wallet, good for your hosting-provider tough..)